# how do I write in the same line that the user wrote?

Tags: c#

The user enters a numbers and the program should make a sideways graph by writing "-" * the amount of digits in the number, but it writes the "-" a line under the user input

Current output:
[image: the output I get]

Expected output:
[image: the output I want to get]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num1, num2;
    Console.WriteLine("how many numbers will you want to enter?");
    num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter " + num1 + " numbers");
    for(; num1 > 0; num1--)
    {
        num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Hi(num2);
    }
}
static void Hi(int num)
{
    while(num != 0)
    {
        num /= 10;
        Console.Write("-");
    }
    Console.WriteLine()
}
```

Comment: If the user has pressed enter, then you're already on the next line. As far as I know, there is no way to do this

Comment: You can use `Console.ReadKey(true)` to read characters without display; check for the enter key and if false echo the character otherwise output your dashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get and set the cursor position in the console, so if you remember which line it is on before the user presses enter for the number entry, you can put the cursor back on that line.

Also, to print a number of dashes of the length of the input, it is not necessary for the input to be digits (or you would have checked for that).

Something like this should be suitable:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("How many numbers will you want to enter? ");
    int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter " + num1 + " numbers");
    for (; num1 > 0; num1--)
    {
        int currentLine = Console.CursorTop;
        string num2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.SetCursorPosition(20, currentLine);
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', num2.Length));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\r\n(Press enter to leave program.)");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Sample output:

```
How many numbers will you want to enter? 4
Enter 4 numbers
1                   -

435                 ---
What happens long wi-----------------------

(Press enter to leave program.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a method like the following:

```
public string getKeyBuffer()
{
    string buffer = "";
    do
    {
        var charIn = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (charIn.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter) break;
        buffer += charIn.KeyChar;
        Console.Write(charIn.KeyChar);

    } while (true);
    return buffer;
}
```

This will echo each key pressed and then return all the keys pressed once the user presses the `enter` key without echoing the `enter` key.

Comment: It would not allow editing of the unsubmitted input though.

Comment: Is that a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to write to something other than the console, where you would have absolute control over what is displayed and where.

Another solution would be to format a string in your code, then clear the console and write the entire thing each time.

Another solution would be to keep track of where you are and move the console cursor using `Console.SetCursorPosition`. However, this is rarely a satisfying solution given the existence of nicer output alternatives.

You can move the cursor up one line with `Console.CursorTop--;`, avoiding the necessity of keeping track of which line you are on.

Comment: 1) Perhaps a bit difficult for a console program. 2) It would be necessary to get what is in the current console window first. The program might have been invoked from the command line with other content already present. 4) That doesn't take care of the horizontal position.